# Conflict in keeping two Apps compatible due to new Android and GooglePlay restrictions

Tags: android, service, google-play, backwards-compatibility

I have published 2 Apps, let's call them A and B, where B provides a remote service which is started by A and, if installed, enhances A's functionality.
Besides the remote service, App B contains just one activity, which is typically used only once to do the initial setup.

Now it seems impossible to update B due to the following conflicting conditions:

a) For new uploads to GooglePlay the target SDK must be at least 29.

b) A service published under this target SDK can not be started from the background, which my App A is doing.

I can of course also upgrade my App A, such that it calls the service from the foreground. But all users, which are upgrading App B at first, will see App A immediately crashing, when it tries to connect to the new version of my Service B.

So the only solution I can currently think of, is as follows:
Instead of upgrading B, I will have to publish a new App C.
The upgraded version of A will then check, if only B is available. If so, it will warn the user, that B was deprecated and that C should be installed.
The App C could also check in its initial setup screen, if A was already updated, and inform the user, that C will not be used, as long as A is not upgraded.

Although this sounds feasible, it is not what users would expect.

So I would be interested, if someone had a similar situation with a better strategy to solve this conflict.

Comment: Update App A to integrate App B's functionality, then eventually retire App B. If the reason why App B exists is because it is a paid app, you could have App A use in-app purchases to unlock the new functionality instead.

Comment: App B exists because it requires the Bluetooth permission, which is only needed in special cases. When I added this functionality for rather special use-cases (Integration of external sensors) I did not want to request the additional permission from all users, although it is only needed (and understood why it is needed) by a minority of the users. But you are right, dropping B now completely would be an option.

Comment: "I did not want to request the additional permission from all users" -- you only need to request it from those users who need that capability, on Android 6.0 and higher, courtesy of runtime permissions.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The original decision was taken before Android 6.0.